# Split a data.frame into smaller data.frames, based on the start and end indices (held in two vectors) and using a condition

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an algorithm that allows to divide my "ALL_DATA" data.frame containing 100000 rows structured in three columns ($Date, $Time, $Value), in smaller data.frames according to a criterion and a sequence of start and end indices (contained in a "START" and an "END" vector of the same length (int [1: 500]).

For example, my data.frame to use for calculations is:

```
ALL_DATA:
     $Date       $Time       $Value
[1]  01/01/14    0:10:00     0.45
[2]  01/01/14    0:20:00     1.00
[3]  01/01/14    0:30:00     1.20
[4]  01/01/14    0:40:00     0.10
[5]  01/01/14    0:50:00     1.00
[6]  01/01/14    1:00:00     0.21
[7]  01/01/14    1:10:00     0.18
[8]  01/01/14    1:20:00     0.19
[9]  01/01/14    1:30:00     1.12
[10] 01/01/14    1:40:00     0.50
[11] 01/01/14    1:50:00     0.62
[12] 01/01/14    2:00:00     0.55
[13] 01/01/14    2:10:00     0.80
[14] 01/01/14    2:20:00     1.12
[15] 01/01/14    2:30:00     2.15
 ...
```

While my two vectors containing the indexes referring to the data.frame are for example these:

```
START:
[1] 2
[2] 5
[3] 9
[4] 12
...

END:
[1] 3
[2] 8
[3] 11
[4] 15
...
```

At this point I would like to apply the condition in which the sum of the $Value elements between the two START and END indices is for example >= 2 and then create the following data.frames:

```
SPLIT_DATA_FRAME "001": (the sum of the values is infact 2.20 > 2)
     $Date       $Time       $Value
[2]  01/01/14    0:20:00     1.00
[3]  01/01/14    0:30:00     1.20

SPLIT_DATA_FRAME "002": (the sum of the values is infact 2.24 > 2)
     $Date       $Time       $Value
[9]  01/01/14    1:30:00     1.12
[10] 01/01/14    1:40:00     0.50
[11] 01/01/14    1:50:00     0.62

SPLIT_DATA_FRAME "003": (the sum of the values is infact 4.62 > 2)
     $Date       $Time       $Value
[12] 01/01/14    2:00:00     0.55
[13] 01/01/14    2:10:00     0.80
[14] 01/01/14    2:20:00     1.12
[15] 01/01/14    2:30:00     2.15
```

**Edit**: as kindly suggested by @Roland I tried using the cut and split functions, in the following way:

```
split(ALL_DATA, cut(ALL_DATA$Value, breaks = unique(c(rbind(START, END)))))
cond <- sapply(split_ALL_DATA, function(DF) sum(DF$ALL_DATA$Value) >= 2)
split_ALL_DATA <- split_ALL_DATA[cond]
```

but the result I get is a set of data.frames divided but not in accord to my START and END index vectors and with the same structure as the original data.frame but with no value inside:

```
$`(2,3]`
[1] Date  Time    Value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`(3,5]`
[1] Date  Time    Value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`(5,8]`
[1] Date  Time    Value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Can you tell me where I'm wrong? Does it depend on the fact that my data struct does not contain only numerical data but also dates and times? Thanks so much.

Comment: Use `cut` to assign the values to groups depending on your start and end indices and then use `split`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, so using the cut command inside the for loop I would have:
`for (i in 1: length (START)) { check [i] <- cut (ALL_DATA $ ValUE, breaks = START [i]: END [i])   if (sum (check [i]> 4)) { "create data.frame and save in .dat file" } `
is my procedure correct? and then where do I insert the split? Thanks again

Comment: Based on your ALL_DATA output above and the Date/Time variables within your example subsets, are the indices supposed to be row indices or bracketing indices on the values themselves?  The former matches your example subsets.  If it is the latter, then my initial thought why your subset data frames are empty is because your `Value`s are not high enough and therefore the ranges are empty.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the indices are row indices that define a range of values to cut the main data.frame and I manually checked that there are values high enough to meet the condition. Unfortunately, however, I can't get any results, could you give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot **Edit**: however, I just realized that I inserted the wrong condition in the example above, I correct immediately, thanks

Comment: So with your first split, rows 2 and 3 above has values of 0.20 and 0.01.  But your first condition split lists values of 1.00 and 1.20.  Unless I am missing something, which one is correct?

Comment: I apologize again, trying to create a simple example to better understand the problem I have complicated things even more, in any case now I have corrected and everything should be consistent. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries.  I believe the posted answer meets your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer to initial comment regarding row indices and using a similar 3-part approach like @Roland, the following should be what you want.

This creates a generic function to return all rows from "start" to "end" (assuming the provided elements are integers)

```
split_data <- function( start, end, dfr ){
  dfr[start:end,]
}
```

This creates a list of ALL available splits.

```
split.frames <- mapply(split_data,START,END,MoreArgs=list(dfr=ALL_DATA))
```

This returns a logical vector with the `i`th element equal to TRUE if the `i`th split meets the desired condition.

```
cond <- sapply( split.frames, function(x){sum(x$Value)>=2} )
```

This returns only the splits that meet the condition.

```
split.frames <- split.frames[cond]
```

**EDIT #1**

Per the comment about saving off the splits, it is probably best to use the `str_pad()` function from the R package **`stringr`** for creating the file names, but here is a base R implementation that should work for you.

```
nchars <- nchar( length(split.frames) )

print.expr <- paste0("%0",nchars,"d")

for( i in 1:seq_along(split.frames) ){
  file.i <- paste0( sprintf(print.expr,i), ".dat" )
  write.table( split.frames[[i]], file=file.i, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE )
}
```

Not sure if you want column and/or row names in your saved outputs, but I assumed they were YES and NO respectively.

Comment: It works, only that in this way I get a unique list where every three lines (corresponding to Date, Time and Value) I would like a separate data.frame to be created so that I can then save it in a text file. Can you help me turn this "big" list into a list of data.frames? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I thought I could build the data.frame with a for loop and save it in a file with each loop. This is the idea, although I have to understand how to consider three lines at a time of the "split.frames" list and I still have to understand how to save in a file. `FRAME=NULL
for (k in 1:length(split.frames)){
  DATA <- split.frames[[k]]
  ORA <- split.frames[[k+1]]
  VALUE <- split.frames[[k+2]]
  FRAME <- rbind(FRAME, data.frame(DATA,ORA,VALUE))
  "save FRAME in .txt"
}`

Comment: Although it wasn't included within the OP, how do you want the files named and what is the file type?

Comment: I really thank you for your kind help @statsetw, I would need to call the data.frames in numerical order (001, 002, 003, 004, ....) and save them in a .dat file separated by a tab. Thanks again.

Comment: I checked your answer as correct even though I miss the last part of saving the data frames, even if it wasn't explicitly requested in my question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ok.  The looping part isn't hard, but can't write out a full solution from my mobile device.  Will post an edit to the above answer this evening.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @statstew

Answer (score 0):

I use the `iris` dataset (from the datasets package) as an example.

```
head(iris)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Let's say we want to create a data.frame for each interval of sepal lengths in [-Inf, 5], (5, 6], (6, 7], (7, Inf]. Then we can do this:

```
split_iris <- split(iris, cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = c(-Inf, 5:7, Inf)))
```

Then you can check the condition:

```
cond <- sapply(split_iris, function(DF) sum(DF$Petal.Width) > 20)
```

And use that for subsetting:

```
split_iris <- split_iris[cond]
```

You can then iterate over the list to export to files (using a `for` loop or a `lapply` loop).

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I'm trying to adapt it to my case, but I would like to ask you for a clarification, do I have to insert the steps you have indicated in the cycle? for example "split_iris [i]" and use as breaks = START [i]: END [i]? Thanks so much

Comment: I ask you this as I have two 500-element START and END vectors that contain respectively the start and end indices on which to cut the data. Thank you very much for your help and sorry if I ask you many things.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions like this: `split_ALL_DATA <- split(ALL_DATA, cut(ALL_DATA$Value, breaks = START:END))` the problem is that as breaks I have to insert my two START and END vectors containing the indices, only that the first two indexes of the two vectors are used while I would like the data.frame to be cut for all the pairs of indexes and for this reason I thought I had to insert your indications in a for loop. Can you help me? Thank you so much and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have no idea what `START` and `END` contain. Maybe this? `split(ALL_DATA, cut(ALL_DATA$Value, breaks =unique(c(rbind(START, END))))`

Comment: I have modified my initial question to make it clearer and I have included my example vectors, hoping to have helped you understand the problem. I thank you for your kind help.